# Why does id(id) and id(id(id)) always return the same value, while id(id(id(id))) "loops" over 3 values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Happens with python 2.7.8. Doesn't happen with 3.4.1.

Example :

```
>>> id(id)
140117478913736
>>> id(id)
140117478913736
>>> id(id)
140117478913736
>>> id(id(id))
38775176
>>> id(id(id))
38775176
>>> id(id(id))
38775176
>>> id(id(id(id)))
38775152
>>> id(id(id(id)))
38775224
>>> id(id(id(id)))
38775176
```

... etc. The last line will always return these three values, looping over them.

5 "id" : always the same value.

6 "id" : loops over three values.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `id()` is guaranteed to be the same for the duration of the object you pass in.

So, `id(id)` will produce the same result as long as the argument, `id`, exists.  Which is forever.

However, `id(id(id))` will only produce the same result as long as the result of `id(id)` exists, but this object is only temporary.  It can *coincidentally* return the same result multiple times, but you cannot rely on this behavior.  I can demonstrate:

```
>>> id(id(id))
12345
>>> id(id(id))
12345 # coincidence!
>>> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(id(id))
98765 # now it's different!
```

So, what you are looking at is just coincidences in allocation patterns in your Python implementation.

### Why loop of three?

In your Python, I guess this is happening.  On the left is the expression being evaluated, on the right is the heap.

```
id(id(id))          [ ]
id(140117478913736) [ 140117478913736 ]           # evaluate
38775176            [ 140117478913736, 38775176 ] # evaluate
                    [ _ , 38775176 ]              # decref

id(id(id))          [ _ , 38775176 ]
id(140117478913736) [ 140117478913736, 38775176 ] # evaluate
```

You can see with `id(id(id))`, with each object taking the first slot in the heap, since `id(id)` always goes into the same slot, you always get the same result... unless you allocate something!

Answer (score 0):

`id(id)` is required to be constant in a single execution instance since `id` is not some temporary object.

Any other expression with a string of nested `id` calls is not really required to have consistent results, because you're attempting to get the `id` of some integer with a lifetime that ends after the entire expression is evaluated, and the `id` happens to be the memory address of the object as the documentation mentions. This is an implementation detail though, so you shouldn't count on it. This detail however, is the reason you're getting these results.

The fact that it's not happening in Python 3.4.1 just tells you that the memory allocation and deallocation patterns for these dynamic objects are different. This is unimportant. The information doesn't really help you in any way.

What matters is that `id` guarantees a **unique** identifier for all objects with active lifetimes. The details concerning what this identifier means are irrelevant to the programmer.